# I need to loop through table and insert new record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to loop through table Organisation and insert new record in User table

```
Select Code,Organisationid from organisation 

INSERT INTO User(userlogin,Organisationid,emailaddress,username,userpassword)
VALUES('AGT'+ Code, organisationid,'test@gmail.com','User'+ Code,'123')
```

I need to dynamically pass the Organisationid  and Code to the User table to loop through and insert new record in user.

Comment: Why do you need to loop? Doing it all at once is a no-go?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO User (userlogin, Organisationid, emailaddress, username, userpassword)
SELECT 'AGT' + Code, organisationid, 'test@gmail.com', 'User' + Code, '123'
FROM organisation;
```

Comment: Actually I need to insert into multiple tables based on each Organisation.

Comment: @Kapil I tried to answer the question posted. If you have a different requirement please spend some time to write a new question that clearly outlines your actual requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639663/insert-into-multiple-tables-based-on-the-other-table-data